# Get post id of permalink for a specific custom post type?

Tags: custom-post-types, permalinks, advanced-custom-fields, plugin-w3-total-cache, plugin-wp-supercache

I have custom post type called `Personnel`.

I have this code to show a specific post ("details" page for personnel) (resides in children themes folder of Oxygen and is called single-personnel.php)

```
<?php
/**
 * Singular Template
 *
 * This is the default singular template.  It is used when a more specific template can't be found to display
 * singular views of posts (any post type).
 *
 * @package Oxygen
 * @subpackage Template
 */
get_header(); // Loads the header.php template. 

//This posts id
global $post; 
$person_id = $post->ID; 
$person_name = $post->post_title;
$f_name = explode(' ', $person_name);
$first_name = $f_name[0];

$person = new Personnel();
$related_courses = $person->getRelatedCourses($person_id);                                                                   
?>


    <div class="aside">

        <?php get_template_part( 'menu', 'secondary' ); // Loads the menu-secondary.php template.  ?>

        <?php get_sidebar( 'primary' ); // Loads the sidebar-primary.php template. ?>

    </div>

    <?php do_atomic( 'before_content' ); // oxygen_before_content ?>

    <div class="content-wrap">  

        <div id="content" class="content-header">

            <?php do_atomic( 'open_content' ); // oxygen_open_content ?>

            <div class="hfeed">

                <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>

                    <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

                        <?php do_atomic( 'before_entry' ); // oxygen_before_entry ?>
                            <?php
                                $image = get_field('image_personnel');
                                $size = 'thumb-large-personnel';
                                $use_large_image = wp_get_attachment_image( $image, $size );


                            if (strlen($use_large_image)>0) {
                            ?>
                            <div class="image">

                                <?php
                                echo $use_large_image;
                                ?>


                            </div>
                            <?php
                            }
                            ?>
                        <div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" class="<?php hybrid_entry_class(); ?>">

                            <?php do_atomic( 'open_entry' ); // oxygen_open_entry ?>

                            <?php echo apply_atomic_shortcode( 'entry_title', '[entry-title permalink="0"]' ); ?>

                            <?php echo apply_atomic_shortcode( 'byline', '<div class="byline">' . __( 'By [entry-author] on [entry-published] [entry-edit-link before=" | "]', 'oxygen' ) . '</div>' ); ?>

                            <div class="entry-content">
                                                            <div class="column">

                                                                <?php the_content( __( 'Continue reading <span class="meta-nav">&rarr;</span>', 'oxygen' ) ); ?>

                                                                    <?php
                                                                    if (!empty($related_courses)) {
                                                                    ?>
                                                                    <div class="related-links">
                                                                    <h3><?php echo $first_name;?> undervisar i:</h3>
                                                                    <?php                                                                    
                                                                    foreach($related_courses as $course) {
                                                                        echo '<p>' . $course . '</p>';
                                                                    }
                                                                    ?>
                                                                    </div>
                                                                    <?php
                                                                    }
                                                                    ?>

                                                                <a class="trans-effect moreinfo more" href="<?php echo PupilRegistration::getSlug();?>">Anmäl dig / mer info</a>

                                                            </div>

                            </div><!-- .entry-content -->

                            <?php do_atomic( 'close_entry' ); // oxygen_close_entry ?>

                        </div><!-- .hentry -->

                        <?php do_atomic( 'after_entry' ); // oxygen_after_entry ?>

                        <?php get_sidebar( 'after-singular' ); // Loads the sidebar-after-singular.php template. ?>

                        <?php do_atomic( 'after_singular' ); // oxygen_after_singular ?>


                    <?php endwhile; ?>

                <?php endif; ?>

            </div><!-- .hfeed -->

            <?php do_atomic( 'close_content' ); // oxygen_close_content ?>

            <?php get_template_part( 'loop-nav' ); // Loads the loop-nav.php template. ?>

        </div><!-- #content -->

                    <?php
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'personnel', 'posts_per_page' => -1 );
$personnel_query = new WP_Query( $args );
?>

<div id="image-wrapper">
<?php
while ($personnel_query->have_posts()) : $personnel_query->the_post(); 
$image = get_field('image_personnel');
$size = 'thumb-listing-personnel';
$use_image = wp_get_attachment_image( $image, $size );
//No image returned, use default
if (strlen($use_image) === 0) {
    $use_image = $person->getDefaultImageHtml();
}
?>
<div class="image-column">
<a href="<?php echo get_permalink();?>" id="personel-<?php echo get_the_ID();?>">
    <span class="image"><?php echo $use_image; ?><span class="clearfix"></span></span>    
    <span class="name font-smoothing"><?php echo get_the_title();?></span>    
    <span class="clearfix"></span>
</a>
</div>

<?php 
endwhile;
?>
</div>

</div>
<?php
wp_reset_postdata(); //Restore to current post AFTER the loop because the_post() is used
?>
</div>

        <?php do_atomic( 'after_content' ); // oxygen_after_content ?>

<?php get_footer(); // Loads the footer.php template. ?>
```

It seems to work fine, but when using any cache plugin like W3 Total Cache or WP Super Cache **it show incorrect post OR give me a file not found error.** BUT not always and there's the confusion. When it happens I could go the admin dashboard, update permalinks and then delete the store cached and then it works again)

My **GUESS** is that these first rows are the issue. They don't seem to return the correct post -id everytime. (Sometimes it work, sometime it don't)

```
global $post; 
$person_id = $post->ID; 
$person_name = $post->post_title;
```

It might be something else also, please give me any pointers if you have any to share :-)

**UPDATE:** (on request)

Here's the code in the functions.php of the child-theme I'm using for registering the custom post type personnel

```
function personnel_with_cats() {    
    //Register custom post type for personnel
    $personnel_labels = array(
      'name' => 'Personal',
      'singular_name' => 'Personal',
      'add_new' => 'Lägg till',
      'add_new_item' => 'Lägg till ny personal',
      'edit_item' => 'Redigera personal',
      'new_item' => 'Ny personal',
      'all_items' => 'All personal',
      'view_item' => 'Visa personal',
      'search_items' => 'Sök personal',
      'not_found' => 'Inga person bland personalen funnen',
      'not_found_in_trash' => 'Ingen personal hittad i sopkorgen',
      'parent_item_colon'  => '',
      'menu_name' => 'Personal'
    );
    $personnel_args = array(
      'labels' => $personnel_labels,
      'public' => true,
      'publicly_queryable' => true,
      'show_ui' => true,
      'show_in_menu' => true,
      'query_var' => true,
      'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'personal' ),
      'capability_type' => 'post',
      'has_archive' => true,
      'hierarchical' => false,
      'menu_position' => null,
      'supports' => array('title','editor','author','comments'),      
    );
    register_post_type( 'personnel', $personnel_args );     

    //Register custom taxonomy for personnel-categories
    $personnel_cat_labels = array(
      'name' => 'Personalkategori',
      'singular_name' => 'Personalkategori',
      'search_items' => 'Sök kategori',
      'all_items' => 'Alla kategori',
      'parent_item' => 'Föräldrakategori',
      'parent_item_colon' => 'Föräldrakategori:',
      'edit_item' => 'Redigera kategori',
      'update_item' => 'Uppdatera kategori',
      'add_new_item' => 'Lägg till ny kategori',
      'new_item_name' => 'Namn på ny kategori',
      'menu_name' => 'Personalkategori'     
    );
    $personnel_cat_args = array(
      'hierarchical' => true,
      'labels' => $personnel_cat_labels,
      'show_ui' => true,
      'show_admin_column' => true,
      'query_var' => true,
      'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'personal/kategori')
    );

    register_taxonomy( 'categorypersonnel', array('personnel'), $personnel_cat_args );    
}

//Hooks for personnel
add_action( 'init', 'personnel_with_cats' );
```

Comment: Can you also post the codes on how you registered your custom post type. :)

Comment: Try removing the global $post just to check if that's the reason.

Comment: Try removing global $post to check. As an alternative,  use $person_id = get_the_ID(); and get_the_title($person_id).